# How to increment a global variable inside a function?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

The variable currentIndex is declared globally and initialized with a certain value say '0'. How do I hold the value of currentIndex which is incremented every time the function is called? In the given code, every time the function is called, the value is reinitialized.

```
function nextSong(e:Event):void 
{
        sc.stop();

 currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

 var nextSongFunc:URLRequest = new URLRequest(songlist[currentIndex].file);
 var nextTitle:Sound = new Sound();
 nextTitle.load(nextSongFunc);
 currentSound = nextTitle;
 sc = currentSound.play();

 sc.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextSong);
}

NextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSong);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *declare* the variable *outside* the function. How you do this depends on the context.  Where is this function being defined?  In the 'actions window' on the timeline in Flash?  or inside a `<script>` block in Flex?  or somewhere else?

It looks like you're in the Flash tool, in the actions window.  If so, then just do it like this:

```
var currentIndex:int = 0;

function nextSong(e:Event):void {
  sc.stop();
  currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

  var nextSongFunc:URLRequest = new URLRequest(songlist[currentIndex].file); 
  var nextTitle:Sound = new Sound(); 
  nextTitle.load(nextSongFunc); 
  currentSound = nextTitle; 
  sc = currentSound.play();

  sc.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextSong); 
}

NextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSong);
```

If that doesn't work, let me know some more details, and we'll sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash CS , you should take advantage of the DocumentClass. In such case you could define currentIndex as a private variable and it will be incremented/decremented in your functions.

This is a much better approach than writing your code in the Actions panel, allows for a lot more flexibility and you don't run into problems due to frame dependent code.